# Ajax with Javascript to send text to html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am learning ajax with javascript where I have a html which has a button inside a div like below

home.html

```
<div id="test">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Show</button>
</div>
```

On clicking on the button I would like to update the  with sample text lets say `Hai ! Ajax here`

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
       }

};
xhttp.open("POST", "ajax_info.txt", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send();
}
```

If I do with opening a text file which contains the text and send on http request it works but I do not want to load a file in my open() method instead just send text to my home.html and I tried like below does not seems working

```
xhttp.open("POST", "home.html", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("message=Hai Ajax Here");
```

How to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: You can't POST to static resource files. Use GET instead

Comment: I replaced GET then also it is not working